# Does every polynomial with a Perron root have a primitive matrix representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, companion-matrices, similar-matrices

Let $p(x)=x^6-13x^4-20x^3+x^2-x+2$ and $C$ be the companion matrix of $p(x)$.

How can I find a primitive matrix similar to $C$ ?

Is there a general method  to transform the companion matrix with a Perron root into a primitive matrix?

Comment: Please recall what you call a primitive matrix.

Comment: Not sure about your case, but in general problems like this are hard. You may try to search the literature using the keyword "NIEP" (nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem) to see if there is anything useful.

Comment: @Jean Marie: A matrix is called primitive, if its entries are nonnegative and if there is a natural number $n$, such that all entries of $A^n$ are positive. There are other definitions of a primitive matrix using graph theory.

Comment: @user1551: Thx for the hint.                                                                When studying the Perron-Frobenius theorem, I wonder why this question (main title) didn't come up in the literature.

Answer (score 2):

You do not ask the right question; in fact you show that the minimal polynomial of a Perron number (cf. below) is not necessarily the characteristic polynomial of a primitive integral matrix.

Let $\lambda>0$.

Def 1. A Perron number is a real algebraic integer exceeding $1$ and strictly greater than the modulus of all of its algebraic conjugates.

Def 2.  $\lambda$ is a H-number iff there is an integer $k\geq 1$ s.t. $\lambda^k$ is a Perron number that has no positive real algebraic conjugate.

Prop 1. $\lambda$ is a H-number iff it is a root of a polynomial $z^n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_iz^i$ where the $a_i$ are non-negative integers and $a_0\not= 0$.

Prop 2. $\lambda$ is a Perron number iff it is the spectral radius of a primitive integral matrix.

Prop 3. $\lambda$ is a H-number iff it is the spectral radius of a primitive integral companion matrix.

Here your polynomial $p$ is irreducible; thus all matrices with characteristic polynomial $p$ are similar to $C_p$, the companion matrix of $p$. On the other hand, the maximal root $\lambda\approx 2.25$ of $p$ is a Perron number but not a H-number. According to Prop 2, $\lambda$ is the spectral radius of a primitive integral matrix $A$. According to your answer, $A$ has dimension $>6$. To construct such a matrix $A$, cf. the paper of Lind

https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/3445712171510E3FF3A2C9543E995252/S0143385700002443a.pdf/entropies_of_topological_markov_shifts_and_a_related_class_of_algebraic_integers.pdf

Consider the irreducible polynomial $q=x^6-13x^4-20x^3-x^2-x-2$; its maximal root $\approx 2.78$ is a H-number (Prop 1). Let $C_q$ be the companion matrix of $q$; we can see that ${C_q}^8$ is a positive matrix.

You can also read the paper of Miss Bassino

https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397596001065/1-s2.0-S0304397596001065-main.pdf?_tid=17ed6aba-01f4-11e8-b347-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1516901032_a3c7f4ccb543e9873b2c267cf58e90c4

Answer (score 0):

Does every polynomial with a Perron root have a primitive matrix representation?

I found a counterexample, so in general the answer is no!

Let $p(x)=x^6-4x^4-5x^3+10x^2-12x+6$ and suppose A is a nonnegative matrix

similar to the companion matrix $C$ of $p(x)$. Then $Tr(A^k)\ge0$ for every natural number $k$, but

$Tr(C^4)=-8<0$. (Note that $A^k$ is similar to $C^k$.)

Hence $p(x)$ has no primitive matrix representation.